# Observable.concatDelayError() continue conditionally

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

i have a list of `Observables` that i currently subscribe to via `Observable.concatDelayError()`.  my requirements have changed such that i now want to delay errors **conditionally**.

if an Observable emits an error, i want to decide at that point if the remaining Observables should be allowed to continue or the sequence terminated.

a use-case is if the error is of type `TimeoutException`, then i would abort the remaining Observables; otherwise, i proceed with the remaining Observables.  ideally, whether i aborted or continued on error, i'd still like the error reported at the end, as `concatDelayError()` currently behaves.

i'm guess i'm looking for something along the lines of: `Observable.concatDelayError(Iterable<Observable<T>> sources, Func1<Throwable, Boolean> predicate)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

Preserving non-timeout errors is more involved:

```
PublishSubject<Object> timeout = PublishSubject.create();

Observable.from(sources).concatMapDelayError(v -> v.onErrorResumeNext(e -> {
    if (e instanceof TimeoutException) {
        timeout.onError(e);
        return Observable.empty();
    }
    return Observable.error(e);
}))
.takeUntil(timeout)
.subscribe(...);
```

Comment: thanks @akarnokd.  this works well except for the fact that i need to know at the end that **any** errors occurred.  so, if a TimeoutException is thrown, i want to abort the stream; if any other error is thrown, i want the stream to proceed but know at the end that an error was encountered.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: most excellent @akarnokd.  that works great!  one side question: is there any advantage to returning the `Observable.empty()` in the timeout case?  things still work as expected when removed --- the IF falls-through and the error is returned.  semantically, it seems to make sense, too, that the error is returned in all cases; though, ultimately, the `timeout.onError(e)` is the most important part.